# Which version of Rumoosh died?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

Note: it's impossible not to spoil in the title. Behind there are more spoilers of Dragon Ball Super Manga 21

> In Dragon Ball Super manga 21 Gowasu dies. I'm confused with all the future timelines thing, so my question is, since when a kaioshin dies his god of destruction also dies, which version of Rumoosh died? Isnt the Rumoosh we see alive in the Dragon Ball Super tournament anime?

Comment: Isn't Gowasu from Universe 10?  Did anyone from Universe 10 actually attend the tournament?  Wasn't it just 6 versus 7?

Comment: No, there is a tournament now where all universes are involved. The tournament you are talking about is the first tournament

Comment: I dont understand if it's a Toyotaro continuity mistake, if it's another timeline Gowasu (though he's being refered as being killed 3 times by Zamasu), if he isnt dead somehow, if they can revive him somehow, or if the manga and the anime are going to take very different paths

Comment: I believe there are already known, meaningful differences between the anime and the manga (but I haven't really watched the anime beyond what's been shown of the dub), so it would not be surprising if they go in slightly, or even very, different directions.

Comment: I see, the tournament you are talking about ends in episode 40, in Japan they are airing episode 80 this week